# how is Jersey hooked up to servlet 3 container

Tags: tomcat, jersey, web.xml, servlet-3.0

For servlet 2.5, a Jersey container servlet must be declared in `web.xml` to hook Jersey up to Tomcat.

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            ...
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

For servlet 3.x, we can do the same thing. But we can also get rid of the Jersey container servlet in web.xml, and put an `Application` subclass directly into it.

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.foo.rest.MyApplication</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    ...
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>org.foo.rest.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ...
</web-app>
```

My question is how is Jersey integrated into Tomcat in this case? Does the `Application` class do something implicitly, or does servlet auto-discover Jersey jar in the classpath?

Comment: There's also another alternative : not include `servlet-mapping` in web.xml but add `@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/rest-path")` in the Application subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how jersey implements it, but there are several approaches they might be using:

- There is a feature called `ServletContainerInitializer` introduced in Servlet 3.0 (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html ) which allows a library/runtime to be notified of a web application's startup phase and perform any required programmatic registration of servlets, filters, and listeners in response to it
- One can create his library as a `web-fragment` which allows you to have web-fragment.xml inside your jar where you can register servlets/filter/etc. Then during startup this `web-fragment.xml` is merged with the `web.xml`. As a result the components registered in the web fragment are treated as if they were registered in the web.xml

---

Edit: (from @peeskillet comment) Jersey uses servlet container initializer: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/jersey-servlet/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java

Comment: First one -> https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/jersey-servlet/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/init/JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java